# Python-Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, I keep getting line 10 'else' Syntax error

Tags: syntax-error

> Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, I keep getting line 10
> 'else' syntaxerror

```
import random

number = random.randrange(1,50)
guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 50: "))

while guess != number:
if guess < number:
print("You need to guess higher. Try again, please")
guess = (int(input("\nGuess a number between 1 and 50: "))
else:
print ("You need to guess lower. Please try again")
guess = (int(input("\nGuess a number between 1 and 50: "))
print("You guessed the number correctly!")'
```

Comment: If it's python, indentation matters and you are not showing any.

Answer (score 0):

On line 9 and on line 12 you have an additional parenthesis right before the function **int**.

Also, I recommend to use a smart editor (like Visual Code or similar). These kind of mistakes will be easily visible.

```
import random

number = random.randrange(1,50)
guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 50: "))

while guess != number:
   if guess < number:
      print("You need to guess higher. Try again, please")
      guess = int(input("\nGuess a number between 1 and 50: "))
   else:
      print ("You need to guess lower. Please try again")
      guess = int(input("\nGuess a number between 1 and 50: "))
      
print("You guessed the number correctly!")
```